# Delete Project in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: visual-studio-2012, project, azure-devops

We have created the Visual Studio Team Services account.

We have created some Project as testing and now we want to delete it.  After searching on some forums, it was mentioned that we can delete it in Team Explorer.  We are using Visual Studio 2012 and we are not able to Delete it and the Delete button is disabled.

I was told that I am the administrator in Team Services and I should be able to delete it.

So, I would like to know how I could delete these test projects.  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: have you right permissions? Login into youraccount.visualstudio.com --> settings --> security

Answer (score 4):

To remove a project from Visual Studio Team Services, navigate to the http://YourAccount.VisualStudio.com > Control Panel (Gear Icon) > Overview

Under the "Projects" area, when you mouse over a project "..." will appear to the right of the project name, click there then select "Delete".  A popup will appear asking you to type the name of the project to confirm its deletion.

[image: How to remove TFS Project]

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting the source control in you example. When u target the Team Explorer u can choose "Connect to Team project" [image]

After that u can rightclick your project and choose delete

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps below. As this is my first reply I was informed I can not use images to describe the step.

Control Panel => View the collection administration page => click on the little black arrow beside the project name and select delete.

I hope that helps.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't delete it from the cloud.

I used the below url to delete it from the cloud.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/81997146-a64f-43fb-9952-57d71542cd11/how-to-delete-a-team-project-from-your-team-foundation-service-collection